# Javascript, how can code be syntactically valid and not run?

Tags: javascript

I copied some code from a JSfiddle, modified it as pure JS and ran it through Esprima.  The result was syntactically valid code, but I run it through Chrome and I get a blank screen.  After 12 hrs with less than 50 lines of code, I need some help getting it to load in a browser.

The JSfiddle for my "syntactically valid" code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Math8Gr/rpkbLwpe/) and the original code I copied from is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tfs2M/2/).  Researching the problem and I know there is some kind of load issue because that is what typically happens with code from JSfiddle.  The document.addEventListener is on the first line for that reason.

I would be ever so excited if someone could explain why this code is not loading.  Here is a sample of the JS, but please look at the JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Math8Gr/rpkbLwpe/) to observe the problem.  Thank you all for reading.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", starter());
function starter() {
    var grid_rows,
    grid_cols,
    grid_element;

var config = {
    gridContainer: "grid",
    matrixContainer: "matrix",
    matrixHeader: "matrixHeader"
};

var start = function () {
    grid_rows = 12;
    grid_cols = 12;
    createGrid();
};

function createGrid() {
    grid_element = $("#" + config.gridContainer);
    var cell; // Contains the 1 or 0 based upon the cell selection
    var newGrid = $('<div id="grid" class="gridContainer" ></div>');


    for (var i = 1; i <= grid_rows; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= grid_cols; j++) {
            $("<div class='cell' data-hover-text='"+i+","+j+"'>0</div>")
                .appendTo(newGrid)
                .on("click", cellClick);
        }
    }

    newGrid.height(38 * grid_rows);
    newGrid.width(38 * grid_cols);

    grid_element.replaceWith(newGrid);
}

function cellClick() {
    $(this).text($(this).text() == "0" ? "1" : "0");
}


}
```

Comment: Dont add "()" in addEventListener

Comment: How do you know it isn't *loading*?  It might simply not be *working* properly (which is entirely possibly with syntactically correct code).

Comment: _"modified it as pure JS"_ (Besides the fact that jQuery is also JavaScript) there is still jQuery in your example. The problem @Merigold has mentioned: `starter` instead of `starter()`. You're never calling `start()` which is supposed to "build" the grid (and which uses fixed values instead of the values from the input fields)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hqmaLg6t/ - according to @Andreas suggestions

Comment: Its important *when* it runs... (Fiddles tend to run js if the dom has loaded already)

Comment: @Andreas thank you starter makes more sense because you only have to use the function name to call the function.  and duh, I never called start.  I see it and it is working. Thanks again.

Comment: @Andreas if you can post a short answer I can close this thread.  You answered my question.

Comment: @BelminBedak thank you for the fiddle, I had to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is technically syntactically valid but it is logically invalid for the following reason.

Replace this line

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", starter());
```

With this line

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", starter);
```

Explanation: This is because `starter()` will run the `starter` function but `starter` will give it a reference to a function. Which is what `addEventListener` needs.

Comment: @mister Did my answer help?

Comment: it did, thank you for following up.  Reading through 3W Schools they always use the function name, but you told me why.  On another note, the reason my grid never loaded was because the start was never called.  From there, the problem cascades because start calls the next function createGrid().  Again thank you for taking the time to explain the event handler.  There is only so much you can learn from Codecademy without some professional insight.

Comment: @mister glad i could help :) Please mark the question as answered. http://imgur.com/oe7mO3R